# How to check that a peripheral is still available before connecting?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I currently have a Swift project where I'm connecting to a BLE peripheral using `CoreBluetooth`. Basically I've got a `tableView` setup, where each of the devices names get shown from an array that they are stored in once discovered. From there, selecting the row in the `tableView` allows the user to connect to the periperal.

The only trouble I have is that, because I'm using Bluetooth Low Energy (LE), a peripheral can only be connected to one device at a time, which is fine, but I want the app to check that the device is still available at the point at which the user touches the row in the table.

I'm assuming that I'd put some code in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` that would verify that the peripheral is available. How would I check to see if the device is still available?

Comment: when the user selects the device from table do a scan and if it appears in results you connect

Comment: It is probably simplest to just connect to the peripheral and start a timer. If the timer expires before you get a call to the did connect delegate method then cancel the connection

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is just to check for the RSSI(Received Signal Strength Indicator) value of the peripheral. If its very low, you'll know its not nearby and you can remove the peripheral reference from your tableview. Hope this helps!
Cheers

Comment: Cheers for your comment. I'm going to try this tonight as it seems to be the best solution. Thanks for your time! :)